# Why does this golang example always run 10 times?

Tags: go

I saw [this example](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5) in "A Tour of Go," and I'm trying to figure out why it only runs 10 times:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

The description says "A select blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case. It chooses one at random if multiple are ready." Once we publish the `0` to the `quit` channel, the `select` statement now could run either branch (publish `x` to `c` or read the value of `quit`), so it should randomly choose which branch to execute. But when I run the example repeatedly, it always runs 10 times, displaying:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
quit
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Because all the writes to the main channel are blocking writes - so will be read in the reader goroutine. After those 10 writes - then the quit channel is closed. So the program will always process those 10 writes/reads & then quit. The randomness statement doesn't apply here as the two possible events never coincide.

Comment: Since `c` is unbuffered and `quit` only has a write after 10 writes to `c`, those writes must complete before `quit` is ready for reading.

Comment: To get something (a bit) random, you should extract "quit <- c" in its own goroutine (and possibly even place above the for-loop routine). This way you have a slight chance of seeing "0" before "quit".